# Mercurial and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-maps, eclipse-plugin, mercurial

I am starting to learn how to use Google APIs for a project that will be using Google maps. I am following a tutorial on youtube(link below), where the subject is using eclipse with a mercurial plugin. The plugin, after I downloaded it, appears buggy and keeps throwing an error: "Command line: hg -y debuginstall." I attempted to open terminal(I have a mac) and use the particular line "hg -y debuginstall" but it cannot find hg. Any way to resolve this error or debug the download? This tutorial was created by Google so I am confident in the source.

Tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVIIgcIqoPw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse Mecurial plugin depends on the Mercurial application, so need to install that as well. You can get it [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org).

After installing it, the error should go away. Unfortunately, the plugin has other bugs which eventually made me give up on it. I'm using Mercurial from the command line or with the excellent [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) (which, despite the name, also supports Mercurial and Subversion).

Comment: I will check that out now. Thanks for getting back to me.